# Is this Phishing or Legit?

Tags: support

I received this email which says the following was added to my inbox.  But when look in the inbox I dont see it. I also dont see it under the thread.   Unless i'm looking in the wrong spot.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a legitimate email sent before [moderation changed this answer.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/452010/5472)

An ‘answer’ was posted on your question. The entire content of the answer is reflected in your email. Since that's not an answer, it was voted for deletion by 3 community members causing it to be removed from the site.

Comment: thank you.  curious, was / is there a way for me to have seen this w/o having had to ask - post this thread?  At least I would not have had to bother you guys.